# Typescript map over a union of arrays without changing type signature

Tags: typescript

##### Context

I have an example scenario that is similar to a problem I'm working on. I have a section list for a UI where each section represents a list of shapes. You could have a section for rectangles that just displays a list of rectangles or a triangle section that only contains a list of triangles.

###### Type Definitions

```js
const shapeEnums = { RECT: 1, TRI: 2 } as const;
type ShapeEnums = typeof shapeEnums;

type Rectangle = { color: string; length: number; width: number };
type Triangle = { color: string; height: number; base: number };

type RectangleSection = { shapeType: ShapeEnums["RECT"]; shapeList: Rectangle[] };
type TriangleSection = { shapeType: ShapeEnums["TRI"]; shapeList: Triangle[] };
type ShapeSection = RectangleSection | TriangleSection;
```

Normally, you'd probably give the Rectangle and Triangle types a common property like "type" to discriminate between the two, but since my UI will only ever show triangles or rectangles in sectioned lists, I decide to discriminate between *sections* instead using `shapeType` as my discriminant property.

##### Problem

I want to change the color of a list item in a ShapeSection and return the updated ShapeSection, so I make a function that does that, but it seems to give me a type error regarding the return signature:

```js
// Not working. Supposed to update color property of one shape
// and return the updated shapeSection
function updateShapeColor(
  shapeSection: ShapeSection,
  shapePos: number,
  newColor: string,
): ShapeSection {
  const { shapeList } = shapeSection;
  const updatedList = shapeList.map((shape, index) =>
    index === shapePos ? { ...shape, color: newColor } : shape,
  );
  return { ...shapeSection, shapeList: updatedList };
}
```

**Error:**
`Type '(Rectangle | Triangle)[]' is not assignable to type 'Rectangle[] | Triangle[]'.`
The mapping function returns a shapeList that isn't compatible with ShapeSection.

##### Question

How do guarantee to the compiler that my function, particularly the mapping function, is returning a compatible `shapeList`?

###### What I've Tried

- I know I could fix the problem by casting the return type to "as ShapeSection" but I'm wondering if there's a more type safe way to tell the compiler that the mapping function isn't changing the final type signature.
- I also know I could use a ternary expression to guarantee the type of the shape array, but it's not very DRY. Is there any way to come up with a more DRY solution without doing a typecast on the return?

I'll leave a link to the [**Typescript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBAWBDADgUwKJgK4FsIwF4YBvGAJXQGEAVALhgEYAaGasgSXoCYYBfGRPlCQoAbgCwAKCgBPNDADKSNJlz4istCABmcZRmx4JkqZtTlUwKIjABzADbmipUPZAAnetHcBLO6JhHOyh4ekMAI1R3AIB3HwATELDcSPc+YzNWXxsHJxIYVw8vKF9-GHhUH1t4KGScVIDwwVQ61PSpUzlzMktrO0cFXp9wQhIpGD0UVGou+iUp1TwAbQAiChoVgF1jCYQpgBkfaHoeqxzHJe2pXgyurJ9z1EGrYbBR0j20GbQ5-UWIVZsdhbAKfVCHY73R6XdrSO7zNDPKCvUanPq5JEogA+UP6TyG4GMUgA9MSYAA5ECwGIeADWflsADpFFhkMgQBBUPEYFAQDBWfFEFBzIU0sh3CA0O5ZDAdLKwOYwSSyTZue5UFAsO43iFzAKhVzAkdYHKwRApNosGAXiN9cKEahKCA3O4ABTjSaIglgX5TTHgJgesEABQ5rSigckEwVMSdLuKpVskYAlL6vTa3sQPcJoPkwRDYPwiGD-WAdgVwLm7VyC6N88bGTgUK7XWCWH54qgAB7JwgAPg9Ew73cIBGL+lD+AA-PlGXO2xX4zAY3GPHwYF59JGJsny+rNdrZ-P9KWWPXIdX4rWbjBSQJ8KXjLwOpI7wAxHxdw1xEIVzswdVkB8ZFkXAC0rQzflkEFe19FXdwPy7d0o09fEMzTNDQLAbdUMncN3BwldnSKOASgZFMMNLMYUJzWAPn0Asz30b5zCLVDHw9TIAHFUAVXxgAAWRQN83iIAAeag+1dexjXoahLl7Ag+1YS5y1omBbF4qIfEElB6B4vidKE5ARNGaTjUUgcUImGToEbZtWy3GBhx7ftBwmZywE7LsYAAQjHXCORgGcwQ3I9GQXUUwlQWNiLSXgcJ3cs70pWBEBgAA3KIZBgAARMgAE0AI1LUwDnRkPX3UrUJY0dxwWQwIEZdZqHcmdSHKktvSYg5ZI0rT+OMxzeugXtn2ssKOuPP1utQgt6E0wzdOQYa0ALManykIA) with the bad function and my fix attempts for testing.

Comment: Your problem is [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581); the only way TS will let you do this (without type assertions or repeated code blocks) is if you refactor to generics instead of unions, as shown in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). Your example looks like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mqo1Yw) when I apply that approach. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yup, this looks to be the solution I was looking for. Mapped types alongside generics is quite new territory for me, so I'll take a look at the TS docs for more info. I'll mark your answer once you post it. btw, do you have any resources you could point to that could help to better understand this particular problem space?

Comment: I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance; but the resources I have are the ones I already linked to above, the two GitHub issues

Comment: No worries. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `ShapeSection` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) where the body of `updateshapeColor` could be seen as safe for each individual member of the union, but the compiler cannot and does not analyze the body of a function multiple times.  You can't convince the compiler to separately notice that "`shapeList.map(cb)` produces an array of `Rectangle` if `shapeList` is an array of `Rectangle`" and also "it produces an array of `Triangle` if `shapeList` is an array of `Triangle`". You have a single operation that makes sense for each member of some union where you expect the compiler to keep track of correlations between different union-typed expressions, but it can't.  TypeScript doesn't really support *correlated unions*. That's the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

---

The only approach that could work looks like "`shapeList.map(cb)` produces an array of `X` if `shapeList` is an array of `X` for [*generic*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `X`", so that the analysis happens just once.  So if you want to keep the same runtime logic and have the compiler verify its safety, you'll have to refactor away from unions and towards generics.  Such an approach is described at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

The idea is that you need to first represent your operations in terms of a "base" object type, where the keys and values correspond to the parts of your correlated type that are different for each key.  In your case that looks like

```
interface ShapeEnumMap {
    1: Rectangle;
    2: Triangle;
}
```

Although because you're treating those keys like enum members, you might prefer writing that out using the enum keys first and computing the base object type from it:

```
interface ShapeMap {
  RECT: Rectangle;
  TRI: Triangle;
}

type ShapeEnumMap =
  { [K in keyof ShapeMap as ShapeEnums[K]]: ShapeMap[K] }
```

That's essentially the same thing.

Once you have that base type, then you have to express all of your operations in terms of generic [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that type, or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type.

To recover `ShapeSection` we can write a *distributive object type* which takes a key `K` from `keyof ShapeEnumMap`:

```
type ShapeSection<K extends keyof ShapeEnumMap = keyof ShapeEnumMap> =
  { [P in K]: { shapeType: P, shapeList: ShapeEnumMap[P][] } }[K]
```

You can verify that the following types are equivalent:

```
type RectangleSection = ShapeSection<ShapeEnums["RECT"]>;
type TriangleSection = ShapeSection<ShapeEnums["TRI"]>;
```

And `ShapeSection` itself is just `ShapeSection<keyof ShapeEnumMap>` (since it has a [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults)), which is a union.  (Distributive object types are defined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109, and the point of them is to index into a mapped type to get a union out if you put a union in.)  So `ShapeSection` is the same type as before, but now you can give it a type parameter `ShapeSection<K>` to represent it generically.

Finally we're ready to write the generic version of the `updateShapeColor` function:

```
function updateShapeColor<K extends keyof ShapeEnumMap>(
  shapeSection: ShapeSection<K>,
  shapePos: number,
  newColor: string,
): ShapeSection<K> {
  const { shapeList } = shapeSection;
  const updatedList = shapeList.map((shape, index) =>
    index === shapePos ? { ...shape, color: newColor } : shape,
  );
  return { ...shapeSection, shapeList: updatedList };
}
/* function updateShapeColor<K extends 1 | 2>(
  shapeSection: ShapeSection<K>, shapePos: number, newColor: string
): ShapeSection<K> */
```

This works because now `shapeSection` is of the generic type `ShapeSection<K>`.  So `shapeList` is of the generic type `ShapeEnumMap[K][]`, a single array type, not a union of arrays.  Then the `map()` callback is seen as having an identity type, so `updatedList` is also of type `ShapeEnumMap[K][]`, and therefore the return type is also `ShapeSection<K>`.

If you pass in a `shapeSection` which is just a `ShapeSection`, the compiler will infer `K` as `1 | 2` and you'll get a `ShapeSection` out. So the function does, at minimum, give you the union-in-union-out behavior you originally had to `updateShapeColor()`.  But it also gives your the presumably more desirable behavior where passing in a known `RectangleSection` will give you a `RectangleSection` output instead of the less precise `ShapeSection`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#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-hEAdjsBYw+weuNzoxU+wC8n3VQAB0OBQPZ7A5Y3gxMym6ECKiKgkBTKEAQr4DNO+AAPy5B+KH-nkbYFA6qDLhhyT8O4ugLjAm5Yi4qBQFgLhhqQKEfpeQ4am+eowPeTbOs+rQbOIVY1tGdYNmxLa4QyMDMqy7JXDcgoGsKyAin24z0bWw4RleDIikRA7wXOLhEUuK6YR43gbuI26qUO6n7uhIjHgMHHnjoo5Dje4BHqxj4cbB2rvl+P5-oREHAaB4GAcy0Feag8EwEhNGoQF+RuFhOHtuaBEDERJGHGRFFUchcVOcpjF2e+9Duex76ceIwIwDxyksQJza6AZLgiWJqBsvgDAwAAPji8mTgVfEqfmFknBpjloNpDqJPOSXNWuxmmTug7KZZpLiEAA)

Comment: Excellent explanation, especially the part where you explain your reasoning behind `ShapeSection`. That was the missing piece of the puzzle for me as to how to use generics to solve my problem. Good stuff!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simplify your logic. Currently, you map your entire array which is a redundant action (also from complexity aspect). This makes TypeScript to get each item of type `Triangle | Rectangle`, and then build up the array back makes TypeScript to assume type of `(Triangle | Rectangle)[]`.

So instead, I think you should not "re-build" the array using `.map()`, but instead modify it at the specific index:

```
function updateShapeColor(
  shapeSection: ShapeSection,
  shapePos: number,
  newColor: string,
): ShapeSection {
  const { shapeList } = shapeSection;

  if (shapePos < 0 || shapePos >= shapeList.length) {
    return shapeSection;
  }

  shapeList[shapePos].color = newColor;

  return shapeSection;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working in the context of React which necessitates that I create a new copy of the shape list when changing the state of the UI. I've tried doing something like cloning the array and modifying the copied array, but the return type still wasn't compatible. Here's the relevant code to said attempt:
`const listCopy = shapeList.slice(); listCopy[shapePos].color = newColor; return {...shapeSection, shapeList: listCopy};`
Error: `Type '{ shapeList: Rectangle[] | Triangle[]; shapeType: 1; }' is not assignable to type 'ShapeSection'.`